# Sharing photo to Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, uidocumentinteraction

I'm trying to share a photo to *Instagram*. So far my method is like this:

```
- (void)shareToInsta:(UIImage *)finalImage
{
    NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"Documents/instagramTmp.igo"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

The *Instagram* option is presented in `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but when I choose it, nothing happens. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I'm already using a method just like this, but for *WhatsApp*, and it works just fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, I think your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I just find out, the problem was that Instagram would only open if the image was bigger than 615x615.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. According to their documentation, the user should see an actual error letting them know about that requirement. Were you seeing that error?

Comment: I'm not. I got no error, it just don't perform any task.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file is wrong

```
- (void) saveimage:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save.igo"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

and

```
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/save.igo"];
NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
```